# Load not visible parts of web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a web page with multiple full width elements next each other, and i have codes js that make the first margin -100% so the second show up. but when it is transitioning onley the first element is visible. is it some solution to make everything visible?

```js
const scrollOne = document.getElementById("scroll1");

function scrollToHpage(page) {
  const scorllPrct = page * 100 * -1;
  scrollOne.style.marginLeft = scorllPrct + "%";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

:root {
  --slides-number: 2;
}

.register-wrapper {
  width: calc(100 * var(--slides-number));
}

section {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#scroll1 {
  transition: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="register-wrapper">
  <section id="scroll1">
    <button onclick="scrollToHpage(1)" class="transtion">NEXT + </button>
  </section>
  <section>
    <button onclick="scrollToHpage(0)" class="transtion">PREV - </button>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Prokop, could you please add your add to www.codepen.io so I can see exactly what you're talking about.

Comment: of course hear you are [link](https://codepen.io/prokop321/pen/XWExmed) we

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure what your problem is here. You have 2 sections, one id=welcome and the other id=name. When clicking next btn, it slide the name section into view. What's the issue?

Comment: The problem is that in transition between first section and second, the second section isn't visible. But yes when the transition is done everything is visible as it should...

Comment: what I can recommend is that you play around with absolute positioning and transition both elements individually. The welcome section is transitioning out to the left but the name section isn't transitioning in from the right.